# OpenGL ES Manually invoking onSurfaceChanged() or onSurfaceCreated() functions

Tags: android, function, opengl-es, renderer

Is there a way that I can call any of those functions in Android OpenGL ES outside the loop?

e.g.:

```
public SurfaceView(Context context){ 
    renderer = new Renderer(){
        ...openglstuff...
    }

    renderer.callOnSurfaceChanged(); // Something like this?

}
```

Just wondering. I know its probably not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Call requestLayout() on GLSurfaceView will trigger OnSurfaceChanged() to call again.

Answer (score -1):

no, these methods are called by the system whenever is needed!

Comment: Your answer needs a little more work. Try posting examples, maybe a links to docs. Just saying no, even if correct without an evidence isn't great